# Auto Click a button until a specific text appear in page using iMacros

Tags: imacros

I'm trying to make an auto-click to a button on a website and do nothing when a specific text appears on the page

Using iMacros, how can I use if a specific text element had the value I wanted so it won't skip?

```
HTML:
<span class="tr-country" data-tr="IQ">Iraq</span>
<i class="flag message-flag flags-IQ"></i>

iMacros Recorder:
VERSION BUILD=1011 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://ometv.chat/
FRAME F=1
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:next
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:South<SP>Africa (Some Random Country)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:flag<SP>message-flag<SP>flags-ZA
```

What I want is to check if the class "tr-country" has the data-tr of "**IQ**" then we don't click/tag "next" button

How can I do that condition in iMacros?

Thanks in advance..

FCI:
iMacros for Chrome 10.1.1 Free
Windows 10 English
Version 96.0.4664.93 (Official Build) (64-bit)